# ¿Existe alternativa a CONCAT() en mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

Necesito una alternativa de la función `CONCAT` en SQL. La razón es que me están pidiendo en un trabajo escolar el lograr utilizar en la siguiente búsqueda por ejemplo una alternativa a la función ya mencionada:

```
SELECT CONCAT(A.NOMBRE, A.A_PATERNO, A.A_MATERNO) NOMBRE, M.NOMBRE 
FROM ALUMNOS A, MATERIAS M, CALIFICACIONES C 
WHERE A.NUM_CONTROL=C.NUM_CONTROL AND M.CVE_MATERIA=C.CVE_MATERIA;
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33333452/is-there-any-alternative-for-concat-in-mysql

Comment: que deseas obtener? por que una alternativa?, que limitantes tiene la función de `CONCAT`?, por favore edita y explica

Comment: si, usa un + para concatenar campos si son varchar

Comment: No puedo utilizar solo + y espacios en blanco, me devuelve "0"

Comment: como que te devuelve 0? eso no es posible, si son campos varchar. podrias mostrar el formato de la tabla y algunos datos?

Comment: @gbianchi considera que el + es un operador aritmético y los campos no numéricos los considera 0. Puede que OP tenga que especificar la versión de MySQL que está usando.

Comment: ¿Es usar `CONCAT_WS` una opción? No es `CONCAT` en sí, pero parecería como hacer trampa :P

Comment: por eso le pedi que especificara la tabla @AlvaroMontoro.. pero seria raro que los campos nombres fueran numericos ;)

Comment: Lo que si puede ser que este pasando, es que no existan registros para determinadas filas, porque esta haciendo un full join de 3 tablas...

Comment: Lo del 0 ocurre incluso si es una tabla con todos los datos rellenos (he tenido que probar, no lo tenia del todo claro)

Comment: en MySQL existe `concat`, por lo tanto asumo que es para otro motor la solución que buscas, no?

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos, la versión de mysql con la que cuento es la 8.0.16, y asi es @AlvaroMontoro me retorna 0 con el "+", y en sí podría utilizar CONCAT_WS pero efectivamente, me piden una alternativa(si es que existe).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En MySQL puedes concatenar de varias formas:

- Usando [`CONCAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat), que devuelve la cadena resultante de la unión/concatenación de los parámetros. Éste es el método más corriente, pero es el que quieres evitar. Ejemplo:

  ```
  SELECT CONCAT(nombre, ' ', apellido1, ' ', apellido2) AS nombre FROM persona;
  ```
- Usando [`CONCAT_WS()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws), que devuelve la cadena resultante de la unión de los parámetros usando el primero como conector entre los demás (es una variación de `CONCAT()` pero con separador, por eso el `WS`: *With Separator*). Ejemplo:

  ```
  SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ', nombre, apellido1, apellido2) AS nombre FROM persona;
  ```
- Usando [*pipes* (`||`)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_pipes_as_concat), puedes indicarle a MySQL que utilice las pipes para concatenar usando el modo `PIPES_AS_CONCAT` (también valdría `ANSI`, o los modos `DB2`, `MAXDB`, `MSSQL`, `ORACLE` o `POSTGRESQL`, aunque [estos últimos 5 están obsoletos y no deberían usarse](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html)). Ejemplo:

  ```
  SET sql_mode=PIPES_AS_CONCAT;
  SELECT nombre || ' ' || apellido1 || ' ' || apellido2 AS nombre FROM persona;
  ```

Las tres opciones de arriba devolverán el mismo resultado. He creado un [ejemplo en DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/krdygCed9rGyQ5rXB8vZvF/0) donde puedes ver los tres métodos funcionando.

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo muy completa tu respuesta, aún que no logré utlizar la variante que me habría funcionado mejor que era con pipes lines ya que al parecer no es compatible con mi version de MySQL que es 8.0.16, en esta página https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/concat2.php el que guste podrá ver si su versión es compatible, pero muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar + para concatenar:

```
SELECT 
(A.NOMBRE+' '+A.A_PATERNO+' '+A.A_MATERNO) AS NOMBRE,
M.NOMBRE 
FROM ALUMNOS AS A 
INNER JOIN CALIFICACIONES C ON (C.NUM_CONTROL = A.NUM_CONTROL)
INNER JOIN MATERIAS AS M ON (M.CVE_MATERIA = C.CVE_MATERIA)
```

Comment: Tu respuesta es solo codigo. Por favor mira [answer]. Se pide que expliques que hace este código (mas alla que a ti vos te parezca obvio, puede que otro usuario no lo vea tan simple).

Comment: Esa concatenación devuelve 0, ya que "+" es para operaciones aritméticas, pero gracias.

Comment: Creo en la publicacion pusiste SQL, pero estas en Mysql? En que motor lo requieres? si el tipo de dato no es un tipo cadena conviertelo

Comment: Es tipo VARCHAR amigo, pero aún así al utilizar +, me retorna 0